How can I find a family of hypersurfaces in $\Bbb A^n$ with normal singular points for all $n\geq 3$?

Let $k$ a field with characteristic not equal to $2$ and $f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ which is not a perfect square polynomial. Give a family of hypersurfaces $X_n \subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^n$ with normal singular points for all $n\ge 3$**

At first, I have proved that the variety $X = V(x^2_{n+1} - f) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}$ does not have singular points if and only if $V(f)$ does not either:
Using the Jacobian criteria we have the following system of equations:  $$x^2_{n+1} - f(x) = \partial_1 ({x^2_{n+1}-f(x))} =\ldots=\partial_{n+1}({x^2_{n+1}-f(x)})= 0 \equiv f(x) = \partial_1 {f(x)} = \ldots =\partial_{n}{f(x)} = x_{n+1} = 0$$ and it has solution if and only if the system $f(x) = \partial_1 {f(x)} = \ldots =\partial_{n}{f(x)}=0$ also has a solution.
To continue, I could use that $X$ is normal if and only if $f$ is square-free. Also if $f$ is square-free $\implies I(X) = \langle\sqrt{x^2_n+1 - f}\rangle$ is irreducible, which implies $X$ is a hypersurface $\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}$ (right?). So, in this case, I would need to take square-free polynomials $f_n \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ which defines singularities and consider the family $X_n = (x^2_{n+1} -f_n)$. Would $f_n = x^2_n -x^3_{n-1}$ work?

Your proposed solution at the end of the post will work, but I think the point of the exercise here is to reduce the problem of finding a hypersurface in $\Bbb A^n$ for each $n\geq 3$ to finding a single hypersurface for $n=3$ and then using the claims in the post to extend your solution.
Here's what you have so far:

$V(x_{n+1}^2-f)\subset\Bbb A^{n+1}$ has singular points iff $V(f)$ does;
$V(x_{n+1}^2-f)\subset\Bbb A^{n+1}$ is normal iff $f$ is squarefree;

So if you could prove that a nonconstant $f\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ squarefree implies $x_{n+1}^2-f$ is squarefree inside $k[x_1,\cdots,x_{n+1}]$ and find a nonconstant polynomial $f$ in two variables which is squarefree and has a singular point, you could get a family of hypersurfaces $V(f_n)\subset\Bbb A^n$ for $n\geq 3$ defined by $f_3=x_3^2-f$ and $f_{n+1}=x_{n+1}^2-f_n$ for $n\geq 3$.
How to do that? I'll put the solutions behind spoiler tags so you can give yourself a good shot at it first before looking. First, the first claim that nonconstant $f\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ squarefree implies $x_{n+1}^2-f$ squarefree:

 By Eisenstein, $x_{n+1}^2-f$ is irreducible: as $f$ is squarefree and nonconstant, no factor of $f$ divides $f$ to order 2, but all factors of $f$ divide $0$, the coefficient of $x_{n+1}$, and do not divide $1$, the coefficient of $x_{n+1}^2$.

Now for the choice of a nonconstant polynomial $f$ in two variables which is squarefree and has a singular point:

 $f=x_1^2+x_2^2$ works, for instance: it's a product of two distinct linear factors, so it's squarefree, and it has a singular point at $(0,0)$. Up to flipping signs around on $f$ in the process above, this gives you that $V(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)\subset\Bbb A^n$ is singular but normal for all $n\geq 3$, which you can find in some textbooks as an exercise.

